# Which way to require('koa-router')?

Tags: koa

I have seen lots of code that does this one of two ways:

```
var router = require('koa-router')(); // makes it a function?
```

OR

```
var router = require('koa-router'); // doesn't make it a function?
```

Which is it? Or does it actually depend on the code in the file?

Comment: There is no "right" way to do it. Voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: But it does change the behaviour of "router" depending on which way you require it. In some examples it works one way but not the other for the given code.